# No puedo editar el footer de mi web creada con WordPress

Tags: wordpress, ftp, filezilla, footer

¡Hola!
LLevo rato tratando de editar el footer de mi web creada en wordpress.

1. El tema que estoy utilizando tiene un plugin llamado "WpBingo" y desde aquí puedo acceder a una sección llamada "footers" que me muestra 4 footers que puedo editar como si fuera una página.
2. Al editar una página, en la parte inferior puedo elegir cualquiera de los 4 footers para que se muestre en dicha página.
3. Al editar uno de estos footers y actualizar no se ven reflejados los cambios. Por ejemplo: En mi página de inicio tengo elegido el footer 4 y he hecho cambios al footer 4 desde el plugin de "WpBingo" y estos cambios no se ven reflejados, sólo se pueden ver reflejados dentro del editor.
4. Encontré que cada footer se muestra como si fuera una página independiente:

   • https://ositosmodainfantil.com/footers/footer-1/
   • https://ositosmodainfantil.com/footers/footer-2/
   • https://ositosmodainfantil.com/footers/footer-3/
   • https://ositosmodainfantil.com/footers/footer-4/
   • https://ositosmodainfantil.com/footers/footer-5/
5. Accedí a mi web por FTP intentando encontrar el directorio donde se encuentran los footers y no existe el directorio "footers".
6. Estoy desesperado, no encuentro cómo editar el footer

¡¡Ayuda!!

Comment: Ya has deshabilitado el caché del navegador? Tal vez te está mostrando una versión antigua sin los cambios

Comment: ¡Hola, Mauricio!
Agradezco por tu respuesta. Sí he borrado la caché del navegador y también he ingresado desde inPrivate y tampoco me funciona, sigo viendo lo mismo

Comment: `footers/footer-1` pareciera indicar que es un custom post type llamado `footers` donde se guardan los distintos "footers", no sería una carpeta. contacta tu hosting a ver si están cacheando php o las respuestas, lo mas seguro es que te indiquen entrar al panel del hosting y apretar un boton